# How do I self-invoke cloud function while developing locally?

Tags: bash, google-cloud-functions, sh

I'm trying to do make a cloud function reload and get invoked on any source file change.
Here is how I try to achieve this in `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "cd dist && functions-framework --target=helloGET & (sleep 2 && curl http://localhost:8080 && exit -0)",
    "start": "rm -rf dist && tsc-watch --onSuccess 'yarn run dev'"
  },
```

The problem is that functions-framework with `& (sleep...` the `functions-framework` keeps running in background instead of getting terminated. How do I fix this?

Comment: should ... `--target=helloGET & (sleep 2 &&` not be `--target=helloGET && (sleep 2 &&`

Comment: `functions-framework --target=helloGET` is continuous, so unless it crashes for some reason, the after-`&&` scrip will never start